# Neither Github nor its other products opening on the laptop

Tags: git, google-chrome, error-handling, github-for-windows

I've been trying to login into my GitHub account in my new laptop for the past few days and have been facing a lot of problems. Whenever, I try to go to github.com, it displays the following message...[![This site can’t be reached. The webpage at https://github.com/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID]
[image]
I'm able to login into GitHub through my phone but not through the laptop.
I tried to download git, but again I got the following message....[image]
Also, in my VS Code, on starting it, it shows [Unable to initialize Git; Aggregate Error(2) Error: Unable to find git Error: Unable to find git][image]

I searched on youtube and tried flushdns, used cloudfare, different browsers(eg.:MICROSOFT EGDE, OPERA, FIREFOX etc.) and delete site settings. I thought there was some problem with Chrome, so i tried uninstalling and reinstalling it, but still no hope. None of them were able to solve my problem. Is there a problem with the site or the laptop?

Comment: If other websites are accessible, are you in [one of those countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censorship_of_GitHub) which blocks GitHub?

Comment: No sir, GitHub is working on my mobile and my desktop but not on the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar Situation.
The issue was that the "hosts" file somehow was overwritten with the IP adress for github and github.com as 0.0.0.0. wich would be the invalid address.

This "hosts" file is in the directory: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

I modified the file deleting the lines with github in it, and the problem was resolved.

Hope it helps you

Answer (score -1):

this Should Help follow the steps in this video https://youtu.be/wR9QAMLUAa4

Comment: this should work follow the steps on this video https://youtu.be/wR9QAMLUAa4